# Creating a custom notification popup in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, system-tray

I am currently working on a C# WPF project. What I want to be able to do is allow the application to minimise to the system tray area which I have done without problems. The main thing I want to achieve is when the user clicks on a certain item within the program a notification message appears in the bottom right corner of the screen above the task bar near to the system tray notification area. I know I can use the balloon tip but this isn't want I want to use. Instead I want to have my own custom window that appears in the same sort of area as the balloon tip but I can style it in my own way.

What is the best method to achieve this custom notification popup. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You want a [WPF toast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906818/how-do-i-show-a-toast-notification-from-a-wpf-application) control.

Comment: not the same issue but discussing on how to customize the balloon in WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557483/wpf-custom-balloontips-problem-with-multithreading

Comment: If you want a custom window, the answer provided in the answer linked to by Adrian is the best option (WPF Notify Icon). The library has a few issues however for the most part it is usable. ... Which reminds me, I have several changes/fixes to the project that I've meaning to submit back to the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the answers for [WPF Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088465/wpf-notifications) and/or [toast style popup for my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461184/toast-style-popup-for-my-application).  The second one is a WinForms app, but the same ideas should apply.